# Apt design pattern for logging every request in Spring boot Java

Tags: java, algorithm, design-patterns, java-8

I'm building a **Audit log** for my spring boot app. I want to track every **POST request** to my web server(even failures) in DB. My code for auditing has cluttered my controller. Can someone please suggest a appropriate design pattern to make it clean, generic & maintainable.

```
@JsonView(View.Student.class)
@PostMapping("/updateStudent")
public Student updateStudent(@Valid @RequestBody final Student  studentConfig) {

    Student oldStudentDefn =                        
                  repository.findById(studentConfig.getStudentId())
                     .map(Function.identity()).orElse(null);

    final AuditBuilder builder = aAuditBuilder().withAction("UPDATE")
        .withSource("GUI")
        .withBeforeObj(oldStudentDefn)
        .withAfterObj(studentConfig);

    try{
        if(repository.save(studentConfig)) {
            builder.withStatus("Success");
        } else {
            throw new ApplicationException(" Student Save failed");
        }
    }catch(ApplicationException e) {
        builder.withStatus("Failure");
                    throw e;
    }

    finally {
        auditService.save(builder.build());
    }

}
```

I want to **refactor** it such a way that this  **repetitive try-catch builder for every endpoint** goes to a common service and which is generic enough for accepting any kind of object so that even Teacher,Section,ProgressReport etc endpoints can also be audited by calling same service but it shouldn't have any code duplication.

Comment: try use `Filter` or `HandlerInterceptor` to intercept the request and create audit log just for post method.

Comment: Thanks for quick comment , TongChen. A doubt with your approach. In case I want to update student obj in /update/student endpoint, I need the old object for example oldStudentObj from student repository to be inserted in audit table and the new one currently saved . How do I get that in generic fashion and also what if I dont send same student object in response after saving but rather if I send studentsettings(transformed for UI display) as response

Answer (score 2):

With Spring Boot you are most likely embedding a servlet container. Instead of developing this feature yourself you can use the servlet container facilities e.g. [Tomcat has access log](https://www.techstacks.com/howto/configure-access-logging-in-tomcat.html) configurable with [`AccessLogValve`](https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/AccessLogValve). It should be enough to output the log file and then convert and import into the to database.

If you need a more real-time solution you can look into a monitoring libraries like [Jaeger](https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger) or [Micrometer](https://spring.io/blog/2018/03/16/micrometer-spring-boot-2-s-new-application-metrics-collector).

Point is, there are easier ways to get this feature than writing your own code unless you have a very specific requirement.

Comment: Well, I have requirement of finding a change summary from oldObject from repo and the new one which is formed from the request & saving to DB several info about the operation(FILE/GUI/CREATE/UPDATE etc) in non blocking manner. Can you please suggest any design pattern I could use to do that without cluttering my controllers.This requirement is basically to display custom audit report to auditors with several details which varies completely from endpoint and which needs to be BA readable messages

Answer (score 1):

Building upon Karol's great response (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54160447/8231165), I would also suggest using an existing Framework for your needs.

One example would be to ship logs via the Logstash appender/encoder for Logback and then to stash/manipulate them via ELK stack (more details here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-application-logs-to-elastic-stack). Logstash has a rich list of output plugins, such as one for MongoDB.

One other alternative would be to publish log events into a message broker such as RabbitMQ and then have a consumer do whatever it needs in order for those events to be stored in a database.

On a side note, all that try-catch-finally code could be placed in a distinct method (perhaps in a Util class).